# Ansible module bigip_pool_member for BIGIP always returning "Changed" status

Tags: ansible, f5

I am trying to add pool members to a bigip pool using bigip_pool_member.

**Tested on** ansible version 2.5 and 2.6

**Result** - Returns changed ALWAYS, even when it is not making any changes.

**Involcation command**:

```
ansible-playbook -i test_inventory add_pool_members.yaml --extra-vars '{"hostgroup": "test-bigip"}'
```

I am wondering if anyone has insights into what could be going on ?

The contents of the playbook are as under

```
--
- hosts: "{{ hostgroup }}"
  gather_facts: no"
  tasks:
    - name: Add servers to connection pool
      bigip_pool_member:
        user: username
        password: password
        server: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
        validate_certs: no
        state: present
        partition: test
        pool: testpool
        host: 14.34.45.X
        name: test-server
        port: 80
        description: test
      delegate_to: localhost
```

**Run Result**

```
PLAY [f5-test] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Add servers to connection pool ] *****************************************************
changed: [f5-test -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************

f5-test              : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to this known [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/40631) in the module.

> When running playbook with `bigip_pool_member` module with `state: present` against live device, each run results in change being made when in reality there's no need for a change.

I'm nor f5 neither network expert but from I understand that happen if you set a monitor to your pool.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/41035) already with fixes related to correct state of down machine. Check if it applies to you, else I would suggest to add a detailed comment on the bug.

Comment: Thank you so much @baptistemm. Looks like it really is a bug. I did try to pull in the patch but it doesn't work for me. I think its best to table this until they fix it in 2.7

Comment: I'd say don't table that will be fixed, always report, because developers can't test all cases. State you tested the fix in the bug report mentioned. You can set my answer as correct also :)

Comment: I am going to do that. Thank you so much @ Baptiste Mille-Mathias

Comment: once created please give me the issue number I'm interested